# Eeeeek! What happened to these badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Noticed this while on the Android app (tablet=Nexus 7) - this user's badges show up as asterisks.

[image]

But when I looked at their profile, they have in actuality a lot less badges than I was led to believe!

Could it be a caching issue?

Comment: The "lot less badges" is by design, in the profile page it's showing only "distinct" badges so for example Jon Skeet  has 4838 bronze badges right now, however 4360 of those are one single [nice answer badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=22656) awarded multiple times. By the way who's that user?

Comment: Baggers? We don't need no stinkin' Baggers!

Comment: @Andrew at least it's not Beggars!

Comment: Needs more "Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek!"

Comment: I prefer baggers.. can we keep it??

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd or buggers..

Comment: @Skippy too bad, Geoff fixed it!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I love yr new profile pic on SO :)) beautiful.. enjoy every moment, my babies are either almost my height or taller.. when they are so little, it's the best time of your life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an oversight - those badges are actually placeholders that we're using in our layout.  Braggers happens to be a deleted user therefore we have no record for these badges.  It will be fixed in version v0.1.4

Comment: I like braggers and baggers,..